# Matching column of a table with current session

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to match the $username variable with the current session username (username of logged in account).

I am using the following code but getting a parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE $username = $_SESSION['username']")
```

Comment: More into about the error you're getting would be nice. Moreover, it's a VERY bad practice to shoot direct variables into queries.

Comment: @favoretti What would you do instead to only pull rows from database where the username matches the current user?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the query (aside of things in my answer), but I'd pass `$_SESSION['username']` through http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three very obvious errors I see here:

`$username` in a query will be evaluated by PHP to the value of PHP's `$username` variable, which you apparently don't have, which in turn evaluates it to "".

`$_SESSION['username']` should be quoted ("" or ''), because it's evidently a string value.

Moreover, I'd rewrite this as:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'");
```

That being said, you don't want to pass any variables from PHP directly to queries without sanitising them first. It's an injection paradise.

[edit]

Also, seeing your error message the error is probably elsewhere. Unless you're really missing the `;` in the end of your line. Also, that error should give you exact PHP line number where the interpretation error occurred.